# Given $f:A\times B\to C$ and $g:B\times C\to \mathbb{R}$, can I construct a composite function $g(b,f(a,b))$?

Tags: functions

Let $A,B$ and $C$ be arbitrary sets, with generic elements $a\in A$, $b\in B$ and $c\in C$. Further, consider two functions
\begin{gather}
f:A\times B\to C\\
g:B\times C\to \mathbb{R}
\end{gather}

I want to know if it is “legal” to construct a composite function $h:B\times A\times B\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $h(b,a,b’)=g(b,f(a,b’))$ and $b=b’$; or if instead I need to define a map $h’:A\times B$ such that $h’(a,b)=g(b,f(a,b))$.

Comment: Couple of issues: To what co-domain is $h$ mapping to? Also a generic element of $B \times A \times B$ should be  $(x,y,z)$, where $x,z \in B$ and $y \in A$ (point is that $x$ need not be same as $z$).

Comment: It's certainly legal to define a function $h:B\times A\times B\to\mathbb{R}$ by $h(b_1,a,b_2) = g(b_1, f(a, b_2))$, but not with the constraint that $b_1=b_2=b$ (since you need to handle all values in the domain).  However, this function I defined satisfies $h(b,a,b)=g(b,f(a,b))$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to define $h:A\times B\to\mathbb{R}$ by $h(a,b) = g(b, f(a,b))$.  This is a legal definition.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @AnuragA. I just addressed the first issue (I forgot to specify the codomain in my initial question). If I understand the situation correctly, the second issue you mention is the same issue that Kyle Miller mentions, right?

Comment: @Héctor Yes that's exactly what I meant as well

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @KyleMiller. If I understand your point correctly, in the event that I want the constraint $b_1=b_2=b$ to hold, what I need to define is a map $h’:A\times B$ such that $h’(a,b)=g(b,f(a,b))$ rather than a map $h:B\times A\times B$ such that $h(b,a,b)=g(b_1,f(a,b_2))$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how you can do it.  (One way to conceptualize it is that if you have a function $F:B\times B\to C$, then you can compose it with the "diagonal map" $\Delta:B\to B\times B$ defined by $\Delta(b)=(b,b)$ to get a function $F\circ\Delta :B\to C$ defined by $(F\circ\Delta)(b) = F(b,b)$.  I could write a definition for $h'$ using only function composition, similar to this one, but I'd need to define a few more functions for manipulating products first.  The diagonal map represents the notion of an equality constraint.)

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Feel free to post an answer that contains your insights —they were very useful and completely resolved my doubt. I have also edited my original question to reflect my doubt correctly and allow you to post an easy, simple answer.